# How does the DefaultValue for Entity Framework Migrations work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, default-value, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to set the default value on one of my columns(IsActive) to a default value as follows but it never works. I've tried using both DefaultValue and DefaultValueSql independently, and as you can see below in this case I'm trying to use them together. Any idea if I'm missing something here?

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.TestDB",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 64),
                    Description = c.String(nullable: false, storeType: "ntext"),
                    Comment = c.String(maxLength: 255),
                    IsActive = c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "1", defaultValue: true),
                    CreatedOn = c.DateTimeOffset(nullable: false, precision: 7),
                    CreatedBy = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    ModifiedOn = c.DateTimeOffset(nullable: false, precision: 7),
                    ModifiedBy = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.GlobalKpiId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.TestDB");
    }
```

Even after doing this, whenever I create records in the DB, the value of IsActive is always false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add that column in the `CreateTable` and try to add it this way:

```
public override void Up()
{ 
  //...   
  AddColumn("dbo.TestDB", "IsActive", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true));
}
```

Another variant is initialize that property in the constructor of your entity:

```
public YourEntity()
{ 
   IsActive=true;
}
```